# How can I redirect an "add to shopping cart" button to another page?

Tags: html, shopping-cart, business-catalyst

I want to redirect the shopper to the main shopping page after they've added an item to the cart. I am using Business Catalyst to build the cart, and I'm seeing a lot of outdated solutions to this problem but not many new.

Here is what the button looks like right now:

```
<input class="productSubmitInput" name="AddToCart_Submit" type="submit" value="Purchase Now" onclick="AddToCart(150613,5623468,'',4,'','',true);return false;" />
```

What do I do??

Answer (score 2):

From BC's old knowledgebase

> Refreshing the page after adding a product to a cart
>
> Add this code in the Site-Wide Template that your shopping cart is
>   using (or link to this JavaScript in an external .js file).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddProductExtras(){
document.location.reload(true);
}
</script>
```

Tested just now,

`function AddProductExtras() { $('input[name="AddToCart_Submit"]').on('click',document.location.replace('/products'));
        }`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `{tag_addtocart}` and a person adds a product to the cart, it will show an alert saying: `item(s) added to your cart`. So if you want to direct a user to the shopping page after they add an item, you can use the following code (this solution uses jQuery):

```
$(function() {

    window.alert = function(text) {
        if (text.indexOf("item(s) added to your cart") > -1) {
            window.location.href = "http://example.com/url-of-shopping-page";
        }
    }; 

});
```

Note: Add the above script into the `Large Product` layout.